# backbone.js app odd behavior with views

Tags: backbone.js

trying to wrap my head around backbone.js and so far I like what I'm seeing.  I have a question about views that I'm not quite understanding.  I'm creating a demo app that uses a form input to append a LI to a UL.  Pretend it's a list of movies.  So I have:

- AppView, the view for my entire application
- MovieView, a single LI in the UL of movies

When you click to add a movie, I want to create a new MovieView and append it to the UL in my AppView.  I've got a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nCEz2/

What's happening is that instead of appending an LI to the UL, each time I create a new MovieView, the old MovieView is updated.  So instead of appending a new LI to the UL each time, I only ever have the first one I added, updated to the newest item I've added.  Any ideas why I'm only getting one MovieView and it's not appending like I think it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example isn't working the way you expect because the `$el` property of MovieView is initialised once so it always represents the same DOM object in all instances of MovieView. So although you change the text of the `li` each time you render a new MovieView you are always adding the same `li` to the `ul` and after the first time you add it thats a no-op.

One way to get the behaviour you are expecting is to use the tagName property so that backbone will automatically create a new li element for each view instance. e.g.

```
var MovieView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');

        return this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).text(this.model.get('name'));
    }
});
```

Then in you AppView.movieAdded method:

```
movieAdded: function (newMovie) {
    var movieView = new MovieView({
        model: newMovie
    });

    $('#movieList').append(movieView.el); 
},
```

Comment: You rock Steve.  Thanks for the input, I should have spotted that.  I was thinking that each time I create a new MovieView it would create a new $('li'), but should have known better that js would just do it by reference.  Nice catch!